How does the quotient affect the complex valued metric? Information geometry.
Take a probability distribution without the normalization factor $f_t(x)=e^{{tL}}$ for suffcient statistic $L(x)=\frac{1}{\log x}.$ The Fisher metric associates a Riemannian metric to a probability distribution. The Fisher metric of $f$ and my own Mellin analogue produce the same metric. Briefly, since a Riemannian metric is attached to $f$ I ask about what effect quotienting $f$ over the boundary curves has on this Riemannian metric.
I calculated the Fisher metric $F_t(s)$ (which is equivalent to taking a Mellin transform of $f$). Take an integral transform for open unit interval $I$:
$$ F_t(s)=\mathcal M(f_t)(s)=\int_{I} f_t(x)~x^{s-1}~dx  $$
where the Bessel function $F_t(s)=2\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{ts})$ is defined on the right half plane of $\Bbb C$ and $t>0$ is a real parameter. Let's say I take a closed subset of all these functions i.e. for all $t\in [1/2,2]$ with bounding curves given by $t=1/2,2$ and glue the bounding curves together by identifying opposite points via straight lines each with slope $+1.$ Specifically take the $y$ intercepts to be between $-1$ and $+1$ and including those points.
It can be shown that gluing $F_t(s)$ and $f_t(s)$ resp. give topologically equivalent surfaces independent of the linear operator $\mathcal M$. It's clear that $F_t(s)$ when restricted to $\Bbb R_+$ defines a Riemannian metric, which intuitively measures the distances between the $f_t$ for pairs. Example, the distance between $f_1$ and $f_1$ is zero (because the area between $f_1$ and $f_1$ is zero).
Hence with the prescribed gluing we obtain a quotient metric $g^{\sim}$ on the resultant surface $S$. We can describe $S$ as a topological sphere albeit with two pointy ends.

Accepting the natural image of $\mathcal M$ to be the right half plane of $\Bbb C$, does the gluing on $f_t(x)$ make $g^{\sim}$ a Hermitian metric?

I am not sure how to rigorously understand $g^{\sim}$ when it takes on complex values and how that affects the geometry of $S$.
This is a diagram to depict the gluing construction of the boundary curves:

This is a depiction of the quotient space, $(S,g^{\sim})$


I don't understand. Is $\mathcal M$ a function on domain $(0,1)$ or is it a function on functions as you've written $\mathcal M(f_t)(s)$? Are you saying that it's equivalent as ${f_t~|~t\in(0,1)}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$? You talk about $\mathcal M$ as a linear operator, in which case its image would be a vector space of functions, but then say that the "natural" image of $\mathcal M$ is the upper half plane. Please clarify.

@BorisDimitrov $\mathcal M$ acts on the family of functions $f_t(x)$ (defined on domain $(0,1)$ and hence it maps that family of functions to a new family of functions on a new function space. In this case the image of $\mathcal M$ is the right half plane of $\Bbb C$ (that is the fundamental strip where the integral converges). Since this is an integral transform we automatically have linearity.

Your question is unclear. Do you have a reference from which this problem comes from or at least the relevant objects are precisely defined?

@LPZ Which part would you recommend I make more clear?

The Mellin transform is a functional functions, it is not a map from $I$ to $\mathbb C$, so the notation is a bit misleading and this is what Boris Dimitrov indicated. Personally, I didn't understand your gluing contraction: which lines of slope +1 are you talking about? Also could you define the Riemannian metric, which is the heart of your question?

@LPZ okay thanks
